# Scanner stops reading randomly when ran from exported .jar but not when ran from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

so today I ran into some trouble while using the java Scanner. I use the Scanner class many times in my project and I never ran into any problem.

Basically, I always do something like this:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        ...
    }
} catch ...
} finally ...
```

and the Scanner works just fine because it's just some simple code. Today, however, I used the code above to read text files with about 17000 lines.

At first the code worked just fine (when running it through Eclipse) as I expected but then, after exporting the project, the Scanner would stop reading after about 400 lines.

I googled a bit and in the end I solved the problem thanks to these answers:

- [Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881861/weird-behavior-with-java-scanner-reading-files)
- [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492520/java-scannerfile-misbehaving-but-scannerfileinputstream-always-works-with-t)

All I had to do was change the constructor from

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)
```

to

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(sql)))
```

It is some weird encoding problem, I get it. But why when I ran the code from Eclipse it worked flawlessy and when I ran it from my exported jar the Scanner stopped after reading about 400 lines?

The code does the exact same thing in both cases because I set up Eclipse so that it would use the same working directory as the exported .jar archive (because it has got some data subdirectories):

1. Takes the same .gz archive
2. Extract a file from the .gz
3. Read the file like I showed above

Not sure if it helps but Eclipse is set up to save source files in UTF-8 format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why when I ran the code from Eclipse it worked flawlessy and when I ran it from my exported jar the Scanner stopped after reading about 400 lines?

`Scanner` has two different constructors that accept a `File` as argument. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29):

> Scanner(File source)
>
> Bytes from the file are converted into characters **using the underlying platform's default charset**.

and

> Scanner(File source, String charsetName)
>
> Bytes from the file are converted into characters **using the specified charset**.

So if you do not specify the `charsetName`, it will use the environment's default charset.

The environment encoding when you run your project outside Eclipse is probably other than UTF-8. To check that this is the case you can write a simple program like this:

```
class CheckDefaultCharset {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

And run it on both environments.

For example, when running the above code from Eclipse I get:

```
UTF-8
```

And when running in the PowerShell (Windows 7), I get:

```
windows-1252
```

To avoid this type of problem it would be better to always specify the encoding of the files you intend to use when using `Scanner`.

Comment: This is it. I figured it was some kind of environment variable problem and knew Scanner had that second argument but I never thought about using it since I never had any problem at all. In the end it was just a simple and stupid problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! And don't worry, encoding problems are very common.