# Scanner(File(String pathname)) gives FileNotFoundException while Scanner(File(URI uri)) don't for same resource. Why?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This fails with FileNotFoundException in new Scanner(file):

```
public class Ex1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // boot.txt -is in its own "resource" source folder in Eclipse
    String fileName = Ex1.class.getResource("/boot.txt").toExternalForm();
    File file = new File(fileName); // File (String pathname) ctor
    Scanner sc;

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file); // FileNotFoundException here
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

But this runs fine without any Exception (class in same package):

```
public class Ex2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    URL fileURL = Ex2.class.getResource("/boot.txt");
    Scanner sc;

    try {
        File file = new File(fileURL.toURI());  
        sc = new Scanner(file);  // fine!
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | URISyntaxException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

What is wrong with

```
String fileName = Ex1.class.getResource("/boot.txt").toExternalForm();
 File file = new File(fileName);
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492520/java-scannerfile-misbehaving-but-scannerfileinputstream-always-works-with-t) contributes to "strange" differences between Scanner ctors, but does not answer this question...

Comment: Well what's the value of `fileName` in the version that doesn't work? And why do you *want* to go via a `File`? Aside from anything else, that won't work if `boot.txt` is in a jar file etc.

Comment: Both are wrong anyway, and won't work as soon as the resource is bundled in a jar/war file for producion. Just use `Ex1.class.getResourceAsStream("/boot.txt")`, and pass the InputStream (and the charset) to the Scanner constructor.